# How do I find 8-bit substrings in strings with ascii values exceeding 127?

Tags: c++, string, search, substring, bit-manipulation

I'm struggling to work through an issue I'm running into trying to work with bitwise substrings in strings.  In the example below, this simple little function does what it is supposed to for values 0-127, but fails if I attempt to work with ASCII values greater than 127.  I assume this is because the string itself is signed.  However, if I make it unsigned, I not only run into issues because apparently `strlen()` doesn't operate on unsigned strings, but I get a warning that it is a multi-char constant.  Why the multiple chars?  I think I have tried everything.  Is there something I could do to make this work on values > 127?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const unsigned char DEF_KEY_MINOR = 0xAD;

const char *buffer = { "jhsi≠uhdfiwuui73" };

size_t isOctetInString(const char *buffer, const unsigned char octet)
{
  size_t out = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); ++i)
  {
    if(!(buffer[i] ^ octet))
    {
      out = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return out;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << isOctetInString(buffer, 'i') << "\n";
    std::cout << isOctetInString(buffer, 0x69) << "\n";
    std::cout << isOctetInString(buffer, '≠') << "\n";
    std::cout << isOctetInString(buffer, 0xAD) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
3
3
0
0
```

**Edit**

Based on comments I have tried a few different things including casting the octet and buffer to unsigned int, and wchar_t, and removing the unsigned char from the octet parameter type. With either of these the outputs I am getting are

```
3
3
6
0
```

I even tried substituting the ≠ char in the buffer with

```
const char *buffer = {'0xAD', "jhsiuhdfiwuui73"};
```

however I still get warnings about multibyte characters.

As I said before, my main concern is to be able to find the bit sequence 0xAD within a string, but I am seeing now that using ascii characters or any construct making use of the ascii character set will cause issues.  Since `0xAD` is only 8 bits, there must be a way of doing this.  Does anyone know a method for doing so?

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) is a 7-bit encoding, so there are no ASCII values >127. How `≠` is encoded and interpreted in your .cpp file depends on the text editor and compiler you are using.

Comment: I’m actually only concerned about the bits. I’m just trying to test the algorithm. That symbol may not be portable, but that is the correct symbol for this environment.

Comment: Then just force the compare to single bytes `(unsigned char)buffer[i] == (unsigned char)octet`. However, the warning about "*multi-char constant*" suggests that there may be some other multi-byte encoding involved, perhaps UTF-8.

Comment: Both `buffer` and `octet` need to be signed (or both unsigned). Otherwise, sign extension of `0xAD` will give `0xFFFFFFAD` (signed, 32 bit int) and `0x000000AD` (unsigned, 32 bit int). Doing an XOR of those will result in `0xFFFFFF00`.

Comment: If on your platform `char` are signed, the actual value when high bit is set will be between -128 and -1. XORing such value with a number between 128 and 255 will never give 0.

Comment: You have multiple problems. The `'≠'` character is a multi-byte character (`8800`) so truncation occurs when you attempt to pass it in `isOctetInString(buffer, '≠')`. The type to hold that character is `wchar_t` and you can then use `isOctetInString(buffer, L'≠')`.  `buffer` should be declared within `main()` or you should remove the `buffer` parameter from `isOctetInString()`.

Comment: @mreff555: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

Sign extension -- *buffer[i]^octet* is really unsigned(int(buffer[i])) ^ unsigned(octet).  If you want buffer[] to be unsigned char, you have to define it that way.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple sources of confusion in your problem:

- searching for an `unsigned char` value in a string can be done with `strchr()` which converts both the `int` argument and the characters in the `char` array to `unsigned char` for the comparison.
- your function uses `if(!(buffer[i] ^ octet))` to detect a match, which does not work if `char` is signed because the expression is evaluated as `if(!((int)buffer[i] ^ (int)octet))` and the sign extension only occurs for `buffer[i]`. A simple solution is:

  ```
    if ((unsigned char)buffer[i] == octet)
  ```
- Note that the character `≠` might be encoded as multiple bytes on your target system, both in the source code and the terminal handling, for example code point **≠** is 8800 or 0x2260 is encoded as 0xE2 0x89 0xA0 in UTF-8. The syntax `'≠'` would then pose a problem. I'm not sure how C++ deals with multi-byte character constants, but C would accept them with an implementation specific value.
- To see how your system handles non-ASCII bytes, you could add these lines to your `main()` function:

  ```
    std::cout << "≠ uses " << sizeof("≠") - 1 << "bytes\n";
    std::cout << "'≠' has the value " << (int)'≠' << "\n";
  ```

  or more explicitly:

  ```
    printf("≠ is encoded as");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof("≠") - 1; i++) {
        printf(" %02hhX", "≠"[i]);
    }
    printf(" and '≠' has a value of 0x%X\n", '≠');
  ```

  On my linux system, the latter outputs:

  ```
   ≠ is encoded as E2 89 A0 and '≠' has a value of 0xE289A0
  ```

  On my MacBook, compilation fails with this error:

  ```
    notequal.c:8:48: error: character too large for enclosing character literal type
    printf(" and '≠' has a value of 0x%X\n", '≠');
  ```